# Find the Impulse response given input and output signals

Tags: convolution

[image: x(t) input signal and y(t) output signal][image]

[image]
I would like to know the technique to solve for impulse response given input and output signals.

Comment: This looks like homework. You could attempt to sketch all 4 cases, and show them here (picture of hand sketch is fine), and we can help you along once we know where you're stuck.

Comment: For this particular question, take the derivative of both input and output signals. This doesn't change the impulse response of the system. You will notice that the new input is two impulses spaced `2T` apart. The new output is made of five impulses. Split the output into two pieces so that one set is the response of one of the input impulses and other is the response to the second input impulse. From this we should be able to get the impulse response.

Comment: Instead of actually finding the impulse response from the given x(t) and y(t), this problem is easier to solve if you try applying each of the proposed solutions to the given input and see whether it produces the required output. Then you can quickly eliminate 3 of the 4 solutions and find the expected answer.

Comment: @AJN  '' the new input is two impulses spaced 2T apart.'' would u please elaborate me on that part. How come new input with two impulses turned out to be spaced 2T apart? and I come to the right answer doing what u have suggested but I am confused about distinguishing h(t) impulses from input impulses.

Comment: now I get it. all there is to this problem is understanding x(t)*δ(t-ß)=x(t-ß).  The only thing is how to distinguish impulse response from the differentiation of the output signal.

Comment: @TeilZeitGott I think `Y'(t)` should be \$Y'(t) = \delta(t+2T)  + \delta(t+T) - \color{red}{2}\delta(t) - \delta(t-T) + \delta(t-2T)\$. There is a *double jump* at `t=0` which produces an impulse *twice* as large as a unit jump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is *one* way to find the answer. Uses two properties of linear time invariant systems.

1. if \$ x(t) \mapsto y(t)\$, then the same system does : \$\frac{d x(t)}{dt} \mapsto \frac{d y(t)}{dt}\$.
2. If the input is sum of delayed copies of a particular signal (say impulse), then output is also made of equally delayed copies of some signal. This is the time invariance property. If \$u(t) \mapsto v(t)\$, then
   \$u(t+\tau_1) + u(t+ \tau_2) + \dots \mapsto v(t+\tau_1) + v(t+\tau_2) + \dots\$.

With these two properties in mind, see the below diagram. The top left input gives top middle output. Using property #1, we know that, for the *same* system, bottom left input gives bottom middle signal as output.

Now using property #2, we need to split the bottom middle picture into two copies of *same* signal delayed by 2T since input is made from two impulses spaced by 2T. Here one of the copy is negated since the input also has a negative impulse.

[image: impulse response diagram]

But how can we split the bottom middle signal into two pieces correctly ? Let's use the properties again.

The input impulse \$-\delta(t-T)\$ cannot generate the output impulse \$\delta(t-2T)\$ (labelled A). If it did, then the impulse \$\delta(t+T)\$ should have generated an impulse at -4T, \$-\delta(t+4T)\$ by property #2. So the impulse labelled A "*belongs*" to \$\delta(t+T)\$. This means that one of the two impulses at 0, \$-\delta(t+0)\$ (labelled C or D) "*belongs*" to \$-\delta(t-T)\$. Iteratively apply this same rule from left to right until all the impulses in the output are accounted for.

Once this is done, it will be possible to synthesize an output for the input \$\delta(t+0)\$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to your question. I have written on a paper and scanned it.
Please check the link.

https://documentcloud.adobe.com/link/track?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:3435116b-516a-4ebb-871a-9375523636a6

Comment: Can you add the photos directly to the answer? That way the answer will remain self contained even if the link becomes inactive later.

Comment: I'll try to do that.